# MySQL query using Update, Sum, Where, and Group By

Tags: mysql

I have a table below named deposit

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 500 | 3 |

When I update the table with the query below I get the following table, which is not what I want

```
UPDATE deposit 
SET deposit_amount = (SELECT SUM(deposit_amount) - 50) 
WHERE comp_id =1
```

What the query above does is to subtract 50 from each of the corresponding comp_id

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 509 | 3 |

But the table below is what I need.
Because seeing the first table and with the query I provided where comp_id =1, we have 100 + 100 = 200, and then 200 - 50 = 150. So because comp_id has 1 IDs two times, therefore we have 75 and 75 because 75 +75 is 150. So we have the table below, which is what I need.

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 1 |
| 2 | 75 | 1 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 200 | 2 |
| 5 | 100 | 2 |
| 6 | 500 | 3 |

The amount supposed to be evenly split amongst the deposits that share a comp_id, even if they weren't before.

Please how do I write the query to suit the table I need? Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the `50` by the count of the records for this id:

```sql
UPDATE deposit d1,
  (SELECT *, count(*) over (partition by d2.comp_id) as c FROM deposit d2) x
SET d1.deposit_amount = (SELECT SUM(d1.deposit_amount) - 50/x.c) 
WHERE d1.comp_id =1
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/BQ3FAN6W)